# Convert code from VBA to google apps script

Tags: vba, google-apps-script

I'm having trouble converting this code to GAS. I want a message box to appear `if cell c54 is > than cell c56`. Can someone help me?
Thanks in advance.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Range("c54").Value > Range("c56").Value Then
MsgBox ("Maximum reached")
Target.Value = ""
End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the below code...

```
function checkValues(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
    if(ss.getRange("c54").getValue() > ss.getRange("c56").getValue()){
      Browser.msgBox("Maximum reached");
      ss.getRange("c56").clear(); // will clear the cell c56
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it works great :) Only thing I miss is that I would like the code to delete what was last typed, is that possible?